# Number of neutron stars by radiation band

Tags: neutron-star, radiation, x-ray, electromagnetic-spectrum, stellar-classification

Since the number of known neutron stars ain't reached yet 4000 at the time of writing, I am wondering about how neutron stars are classified in terms of their radiation spectrum. Clearly, some neutron stars can change their emission from radio to higher frequencies, but this means that the way of counting must be somehow reflected within each specific classifier.

So far I've seen a number of different catalogues available on the Internet, including the following ones for pulsars and magnitars respectively
https://www.atnf.csiro.au/research/pulsar/psrcat/
[https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/~pulsar/magnetar/main.html](https://www.physics.mcgill.ca/%7Epulsar/magnetar/main.html)

Ideally, I'd love to see a pivot table, which would summarize the number of all known neutron stars by their emission bands, including

- Radio
- Infrared
- Visible
- Ultraviolet
- X-rays
- gamma-rays

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Crab pulsar is famously bright in all of those bands.

Comment: They generally aren't classified according to their spectrum. They are either discovered as pulsars (mostly radio) or as part of binary systems (mostly radio and X-ray) and sometimes both. But your Q is clear enough.